# How to add character to content of post?

Tags: plugins, categories, posts

In per posts, there are **"oo/x/".**

How to add "0" before "x" if length(x) <10 ?

Example:

> x=12345678 ; length(x) = 8, so add "00" before x ===> x=0012345678
>
> x=1234567 ; length(x) = 7, so add "000" before x ===> x=0001234567
>
> x=123456789 ; length(x) = 9, so add "0" before x ===> x=0123456789

Do you understand ? Sorry for my poor English ! Thank you very much !

Comment: [What have  you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com/)

Comment: What's your language?

Comment: If you are effectively asking "How to pad a number with leading zeros", search for that.

Answer (score 0):

In ANSI C:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
   int x = 12345678;
   printf("x = %010d\n", x);
   return 0;
}
```

Note the %010d, where % is a format specifier which will be replaced by a following argument, the 0 being a flag which pads 0's, and the maximum number of 0's.

Read more [here - printf()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/printf/)

If this is for Java, you can do this using System.out.printf(); in the same way.

**EDIT**: Now that it's clear on where the problem domain lies (in this case WordPress), then you can use PHP.

See the following barebones example using [sprintf()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php) in PHP:

```
<?php
   // ...
   $x = 12345678;
   $yourString = sprintf(nl2br("x = %010d\n"), $x); 
   // ...

   echo $yourString;
?>
```

How you are printing out the values depends on how you're retrieving your information and your layout, but this is a simple example that answers the question.